# What do you call pants that don't go to the end of the feet?

Tags: word-request, vocabulary

Simply:

[image]

what do you call these pants? Maybe *knickers*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This style ending around the calf is called [***capri pants***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/capri+pants). Another type that ends above the ankle is called ***flood pants***. A similar style from the 1950's is called ***pedal pushers***, and an even older style is called ***knickerbockers***. Most generally, these are all types of ***three-quarter pants***.

Answer (score 4):

The standard British term is [**Pedal Pushers**](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/pedal-pushers):

> calf-length trousers or jeans worn by women

Fashion items have a whole variety of names to embrace the subtlety of variations in length and design, which probably extend beyond a plain language issue. Because of fashion we also find them called *capri pant*, *leggings* and a whole variety of other synonyms.

As a side note, in British English, both the words *pants* and *knickers* would refer to undergarments.

In historical times, a similar garment might be called [knickerbockers](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/knickerbockers) but that word is almost exclusively used for historical costumes.

Comment: As a BrEng speaker in my 20s, I would use neither "pedal pushers" nor "knickerbockers". I've heard of both terms, but both seem so dated to me that I'm not even aware of their definitions.